# graph paper interaction in swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm picturing a graph paper like interface, as you click on any given box within the graph it gets colored in. I'm doing this to draw rough shape outlines.

My question is what is the best approach to do this? Draw the lines for the graph and track where the touches occur and color accordingly? Make some array of buttons? Maybe using spritekit?

I'm not too worried about efficiency as I'm not doing anything too complicated but I'm just trying to find some common design ideas behind it.

Something visually similar to this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish some pretty complex behaviours with a `UICollectionView` and a custom layout. UICollectionView is nice because it manages taps and drawing each cell individually, which should vastly simplify things for you.

Comment: Hmm. might dragging behavior be possible? For instance, I want to click on a box and drag my finger four boxes over, highlighting all along the way.

Comment: Depending upon how you receive tap events on your UICollectionViewCells, you should be able to do this.